# Dynamically assign port numbers in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to dynamically assign port numbers in kubernetes?

Use Case: I have logstash, Kafka, Cassandra and other services running in kubernetes and I create multiple pipelines in different namespaces.

Everytime I create a pipeline, I need to change the container ports for each pod so that there won't be any port conflict.

I am looking for something where in kubernetes can give me a unused port number from the pool or an option to create a named port like kafka_port or logstash_port so that I do not have to worry about changing the container ports for each pipeline.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

For pods, you dont need to randomize ports as each of them has its own networking namespace. Unless you use hostNetwork.

For services, NodePort type of service will be  assigned random high ports regardless of the port numbers your pods listen on

Comment: so, what would be the containerport in that case? should i leave it blank?           
    ports:
            - containerPort: 38060

Comment: `containerPort` is the actual port that software in POD is listening on, so lets say you have apache on port 8080 that would be the container port